# Cognos Report Studio Date slicers

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I using a Report Studio with Cognos 10.1. I have a report in which I should implement a prompt like Last month and Last week. The problem is that I should implement  the prompt without using a Detailed filters (for example with slicers or any other ways). I have no dimension and yerarchy for month and week.How I should do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to slice by last month/last week.

You have no dimension containing month or week.

What dimensions do you have?

The short answer is that you first need to add months and weeks to your existing date dimension as you do not currently have enough information in the cube to do it.

Is this on TM1 or Transformer or is it ROLAP?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how you can do it will depend on your database.  But basically you'll need to implement your own relative logic on the dates.  As an example, for last week you might do something like

```
IF ?DateTypePrompt? = 'PRIOR WEEK'
   then YourDate between (CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS).
...
```

Comment: that is a filter, not a slicer.

Comment: What sort of package/back end are you using?  A cube, TM1, a DMR?